# Does enabling Compliance BCC Emails include mail sent from APEX classes?

Tags: email, apex-email-service, email-alert

If the option Compliance BCC Email is enabled, will emails sent from APEX classes be bcc'd as well?
Also I am assuming it includes mails from Workflows.

Thanks
Nawshine

Comment: this is readily testable using anonymous apex - did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I just tested it and it for sure send BBC email even if the mail is send from APEX.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
// Set recipients to two contact IDs.
// Replace IDs with valid record IDs in your org.
message.toAddresses = new String[] { 'xxxxx@xxxx.com' };
message.optOutPolicy = 'FILTER';
message.subject = 'Opt Out Test Message';
message.plainTextBody = 'This is the message body.';
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = 
    new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
         Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
if (results[0].success) {
    System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
} else {
    System.debug('The email failed to send: '
          + results[0].errors[0].message);
}
```

It just exclude the system email.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_compliancebcc.htm&language=en_US